# Do I need to create a new project for second SENDER_ID for GCM 3rd party server?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) XMPP connection running with Android app clients and Ubuntu server. The server documentation (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs) discusses differences between release (gcm-xmpp.googleapis.com:5235) and pre-productions (gcm-preprod.googleapis.com:5236) GCM connections from server. However, the wording in the section states the messaging is routed from to the server according to the SENDER_ID rather than the URL:port the server has registered at:

> The CCS XMPP endpoint runs at gcm-xmpp.googleapis.com:5235. When testing functionality (with non-production users), you should instead connect to gcm-preprod.googleapis.com:5236 (note the different port). Regular testing on preprod (a smaller environment where the latest CCS builds run) is beneficial both for isolating real users from test code, as well as for early detection of unexpected behavior changes. Note that a connection receives upstream messages destined for its GCM sender ID, regardless of which environment (gcm or gcm-preprod) it is connected to. Therefore, test code connecting to gcm-preprod.googleapis.com:5236 should use a different GCM sender ID to avoid upstream messages from production traffic being sent over test connections.

Since the SENDER_ID is the Project Number, does this imply I need to create a second version of the project with GCM enabled to run production and pre-production versions of my GCM 3rdp party server concurrently?

Comment: Yes, you will need to create a second project on the Developers Console for preprod. It's a good way of separating test code from production, especially when you have a lot of traffic/activity in prod.

Comment: if you have already released an app it would be good idea to use a different sender id while testing so that the existing users don't recieve your test messages. If you are only starting out using the same sender id is fine. But when you release your first version you should get a second one.

Comment: Based on the these comments from Koh and e4c5 I have made some progress, I have created a test version of the app in developer console and created credential for GCM API in the testapp project. App server registers successfully with the new SENDER_ID and Password. The clients messages routed for the testapp SENDER_ID do not reach the testapp server. It appears I need to have the client re-register to obtain a new reg_id from play API using the testapp SENDER_ID. More changes than I hoped when just trying to revise a production app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, I created a new test version of the product and generated server credentials for the test project. Once the test variants of the android client re-registered for GCM using the SENDER_ID of the test server, they were able to send and receive messages with the new test server. Production server and test server are running in parallel on the network with test client and production clients routing the the appropriate servers.